# PHP Function does not return key

Tags: php, wordpress

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here... PHP version 5.6.27 using wordpress 4.7.1. I created this as a custom plugin. My page returns the result as "fail", tried 2 different page titles and both return "fail", this tells me it is not getting the page title (location) in the function and the function is failing returning the else.

```
    $locations = array(
    array(
        'location'  => 'About',
        'telephone' => '0121 34838383',
        'email'     => 'example@example.com'
    )
);

function telephone_shortcode() {
    global $locations;
    $title = get_the_title();
    $key = array_search($title, array_column($locations, 'location'));
    if ($key)
        return $locations[$key]['telephone'];
    else
        return 'fail';
}
add_shortcode('telephone', 'telephone_shortcode');
```

[telephone] - returns "fail"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_search](http://php.net/array_search) returns 0 if the element being searched for is the first element in the array. 0 == false in php (look up "truthy values in php") Change the check in the if statement to

```
if($key !== false)
```

Everything else can remain the same. Using the `!==` tells php to check if the value matches exactly.

Answer (score 2):

For this configuration when you have only one page "About" the result of this:

```
array_search($title, array_column($locations, 'location'));
```

is 0. And when you check in this:

```
if ($key)
```

for "if" the $key parameter is equal false (because its value is zero). Make this function like this:

```
function telephone_shortcode() {
    global $locations;
    $title = get_the_title();
    $key = array_search($title, array_column($locations, 'location'));
    if (false !== $key)
        return $locations[$key]['telephone'];
    else
        return 'fail';
}
```

and everything begins to work. For education read PHP Dock: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting